# describe-bindings not working as expected

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, help

Spacemacs Help `SPC h d b` (`describe-bindings`) is not working as expected.
I type `SPC h d b`, and then enter the bindings:

`SPC f e d   not listed in the minibuffer, but the binding works
SPC f e R   not listed in the minibuffer, but the binding works
SPC r e     not listed in the minibuffer, but the binding works
SPC r y     not listed in the minibuffer, but the binding works
SPC h d b   is listed in mini buffer, but I have to scroll down to see it.
SPC r m     when attempting this, minibuffer says, "SPC r m is undefined"
SPC r r     when attempting this, minibuffer says, "SPC r r is undefined"`

The last two do not work, but the Spacemacs Registers bindings are listed in https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#registers

They all list several key bindings, but not the one I entered:
[image: Screenshot_describe-bindings]

How to find keybindings in the Emacs help?

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and Ivy on Linux.

Comment: Some descriptions list only one of the bindings for a given command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're looking for `SPC h d k`. `SPC h d b` takes in the description of the binding you're looking for. Whereas `SPC h d k` takes in a key combination and describes what function it's mapped to.

An example:
if you type `SPC h d k` followed by `SPC f e d` you the following.

[image: result of describing key presses]

And now if you use `SPC h d b` and (instead of `SPC f e d`) type in `spacemacs/find-dotfile` you find it.

[image]

Comment: No, I am using SPC h d b, as my screen shot shows the "Bindings" prompt.  The SPC h d k would have a "Describe key" prompt.

Comment: I realize that. What I'm saying is that is that the answer to your question `how to find keybindings in emacs help' is SPC h d k. The "Bindings" prompt is not meant search for what you entered "SPC f e d". SPC h d k takes keys as input and shows you the keybinding, which is what you wanted. SPC h d b takes a description of a function and shows you the keys to which that function is bound (if any).

Comment: Now I see the light.  So yes, SPC h d k (describe-key) works as you described.  describe-key is what I should have been using.  Thanks for your patience Piglet.